# Crop an image into multiple images horizontally

Tags: windows, image-editing

Is there a software (Windows) that can handle cropping of an (one) image file into multiple files ? I mean for example we scan an A4 paper and I want to specify some lines and the program splits my doc to multiple images.

[image: I mean This]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php):

- free
- open source
- cross-platform
- CLI
- support most image formats
- can [crop](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop).

To crop:
`convert -crop WxH+X+Y`, with:

- W=width of section you want (after your resize if desired)
- H=height of section you want
- X=initial start x position (upper left corner of section you want)
- Y=initial start y position (upper left corner of section you want)

Example: `convert paged.gif -crop 32x32+16+16  crop_page.gif`.

See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop

Comment: I Wanted customized height ... i dont wanna to specify height i wanna do it GUI !

Answer (score 1):

Yo can use [GIMP](http://gimp.org).

Open the image, position image guides, either manually by clicking on the rulers at the windows borders and dragging then to image, or by percent/pixel position in `Image->guides`, then export the sub-images as defined by the guides in `filters->web->slice`  (just ignore the HTML/Javascript options if you are not using them).
Image slices are named according to their position in the image.

If you need to automate the placement of the guides for cutting, it can be done in either the Python or Script-fu consoles that come with the program, by calling `gimp-image-add-hguide`. (ask in a comment if you need further explanations on how to do this)